# Bootstrap - Nav bar not working correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my project, I implement bootstrap. I also make use of the full navbar that bootstrap provides. I set a custom colour and height to this navbar. When making the browser window smaller, the hamburger icon appears as expected.

When pressing the hamburger icon, none of the menu items appear. I discover that if I make my navbar larger in height, the menu items appear below. However I want the navbar to stay the height it currently is.

Does Anybody know how to move the menu items, maybe to the right to allow them to be seen when the hamburger icon is pressed? This is of course without changing the height of the navbar. Thank you.

**Here is my existing code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
        <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a> -->
        <div class="imageDiv">
            <img  class="navbar-brand barberImg" src="{% static 'icon.png' %}" width="63px" alt="Image of man getting haircut">
        </div>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
              <a class="nav-link"  href="#" style="color: white; margin-left: 100px;">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </ul>
        </div>
</nav>





.navbar{ 
    background-image: none;
    background-color: #191919 !important;
    height: 4.9em;
}

.imageDiv {
    background-color: #CED0CE;
    width: 98px;
    height: 80px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: -16px;
}

.barberImg {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 6px;
    left: 15px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 991px) {
    .imageDiv {
      position: relative;
      bottom: 8px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think you may not see any nav bar items, because they are collapsed. I added a few list items to you navigation, and they then appear once you click on the hamburger icon. https://www.bootply.com/ji5Acyk2fv Try using Firefox's web tool: "Responsive Design Tool"

Comment: @Getcodingoncloud Hello. I have added a few more items, however I still see no change. I still cannot view my list items.

Comment: @Getcodingoncloud I do not think they are collapsed either.

Comment: @Getcodingoncloud Do you think any of the css causes this? Check my original post for it.

Comment: @Getcodingoncloud I have discovered the issue for me. When I remove the height on ** navbar** , the navbar collapses. Do you have any suggestions to encounter this problem?

Comment: If you remove height, it will also change the background color of the submenu items.

Comment: @Getcodingoncloud Ok. Do you know how to remove the collapse animation for hamburger icon?

Comment: This maybe: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/accessibility/#reduced-motion via: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/ (when I added animation:none; to the .navbar class the navbar list flattened out)

Comment: @Getcodingoncloud Perfect! Thank you.